# how to split a search expression, keeping parenthsis and removing quotes

Tags: c#

I'm working on a search expression in c# and I need to split a string input in following manner

input:

```
("always use" OR "bar") OR ("Hello" AND "market cost")
```

output:

```
(
always use
OR
bar
)
OR
(
Hello
AND
market cost
)
```

Kindly suggest a way by which I could split it in the above manner.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

As you mentioned in the comment, it should also work with nested parenthesis. So I changed the code to following:

```
List<string> output = new List<string>();
string input = "(\"always use\" OR \"bar\") OR (\"Hello\" AND \"market cost\")OR((\"IT\"AND\"P T\")AND(\"PO\"NOT\"pop good\"))";
var openSplit = input.Split('(');
for (int i = 0; i < openSplit.Length; i++)
{
    if (openSplit[i] == "")
    {
        // put a '(' on
        output.Add("(");
    }
    else
    {
        var closeSplit = openSplit[i].Split(')');
        for (int j = 0; j < closeSplit.Length; j++)
        {
            var quoteSplit = closeSplit[j].Split('"');
            foreach (var quote in quoteSplit)
            {
                if (quote != "")
                {
                    output.Add(quote.Trim());
                }
            }
            // put a ')' on the end, but not if it's the last one
            if (j < closeSplit.Length - 1)
            {
                output.Add(")");
            }
        }
        // put a '(' on the end, but not if it's the last one
        if (i < openSplit.Length - 1)
        {
            output.Add("(");
        }
    }
}
```

This generates following output printing each value from `output`

```
(
always use
OR
bar
)
OR
(
Hello
AND
market cost
)
OR
(
(
IT
AND
P T
)
AND
(
PO
NOT
pop good
)
)
```

**OLD SOLUTION** according to your initial question:
Here is a solution without Regex. The advanced problem for your requirements where, that you don't always split `' '`, only for the `') OR ('`

```
List<string> output = new List<string>();
string input = "(\"always use\" OR \"bar\") OR (\"Hello\" AND \"market cost\")";
string[] firstSplit = input.Split('"');
for (int i = 0; i < firstSplit.Length; i++)
{
    firstSplit[i] = firstSplit[i].Trim();
    // in case of the ') OR (' which has be splitted too
    if (firstSplit[i].Contains(")") && firstSplit[i].Contains("("))
    {
        string[] secondSplit = firstSplit[i].Split(' ');
        for (int j = 0; j < secondSplit.Length; j++)
        {
            output.Add(secondSplit[j]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        output.Add(firstSplit[i]);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
(
always use
OR
bar
)
OR
(
Hello
AND
market cost
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate it :)

Comment: hey, i ran the code and the "always use" getting split as well :(

Comment: @roj123 i made changes 39 minutes ago, but with this code above it should work, i copy and pasted it from here to check now and it worked

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the edit. the code works. Thanks again :)

Comment: Code works for this particular example but fails with nested parenthesis :(

Comment: have you an example? then i may have a look at it ;)

Comment: ("always use" OR "bar") OR ("Hello" AND "market cost")OR(("IT"AND"P T")AND("PO"NOT"pop good"))

Comment: @roj123 have a look at my updates answer. But now you have to vote up the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for your time, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called *tokenization*, or *lexing*. It's easier to search info on this topic when you know the term :)

The next step would be *parsing*. There are many tools available to facilitate this job (take a look at ANTLR) for instance.

But if you want a quick solution without additional libraries to the *lexing* problem only, you can do so easily with a regex:

```
(?<v>[()]|\b(?:OR|AND)\b)|"(?<v>.*?)"
```

[See demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3Cv%3E%5B()%5D%7C%5Cb(%3F%3AOR%7CAND)%5Cb)%7C%22(%3F%3Cv%3E.*%3F)%22&i=(%22always%20use%22%20OR%20%22bar%22)%20OR%20(%22Hello%22%20AND%20%22market%20cost%22)). Just loop through all the matches, and extract the value of the `v` group for each match.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.  I will look into this, I'm relatively new to coding so it would take some time for the advance stuff. :)